# Python - Why do we have to initialise the identifier in while loop but not in for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I learned Visual Basic before and now I'm learning Python. I realized that in Python, we don't have to initialize a value for the identifier in `for loop`, but it's the other way round in `while loop`. It looks unfamiliar to me as in Visual Basic, we have to declare a variable as the identifier in both loops.

For example, from Python wiki,

```
x = 1
while True:
    print "To infinity and beyond! We're getting close, on %d now!" % (x)
    x += 1
```

runs perfectly. However, after I commented `x = 1`, it generates an error. Why can't it run like `for loop` where `x` starts from 0?

In addition, even if we assign a value for the identifier in `for loop`, for example,

```
num = 10
for num in range(5):
    print num
print num
```

the loop will overwrite the value of the assignment. Why is it so?

I know there are plenty of `for loop` and `while loop` questions here, but mostly they are case studies of OP's code. What I want is a more general explanation about the Python structure itself and some underlying operations of the language when `for loop` or `while loop` is executed. Also, in this case, I'm referring to Python 2.7.11. I will be very grateful if you can point out the difference in terms of the structure for 3.5.1. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I really don't know what kind of answer you expect. You already seem to know how while and for loops work. Is understanding of variable assignment the problem here?

Comment: In python you cannot use a variable without assigning a value to it first. So when you do not set `x = 1` python won't know what `x` is.
In `for` loop `num` is used as iterator, so this command sets it's value to each value from the list in each loop pass, and `range(5)` produces such list (array) of integer values from 0 to 4

Comment: @timgeb Please refer to my reply to pivanchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = 1
while True:
    print "To infinity and beyond! We're getting close, on %d now!" % (x)
    x += 1
```

If you comment `x = 1`, this line raises an error:

```
x += 1
```

because it means, `x = x + 1`, as x is not defined, it raises an error(python doesn't know for what value add 1)

```
num = 10
for num in range(5):
    print num
print num
```

you're using the same name for both variables, inside loop and outside of this, that's why you have another value of `num` inside a loop.

Good practice is to have another name for variables inside a loop variable, because you really don't need to have the same for loop variable, as you have outside a loop

so, you can write something like this:

```
num = 10
for i in range(5):
    # play with num and i variables
    num += i * 2
 print num
```

Comment: By using the name iter you are masking the built-in function iter, so that's probably not a very good name for your example.

Comment: @timgeb, yeah, you're right. using this example I want to show the idea how to use variables inside the loop and outside the loop. But your comment makes sense. Thank you, I'll rename it

Comment: @pivanchy You partially answered my question. How come in `while loop`, `x` will not start from 0 like how it is in `for loop`? For example, we can write something like `for x in range(5)` in `for loop`, and `x` will be automatically bound to 0. In `while loop` though, when we write `while x <5`, it raises an error if `x` is not assigned beforehand because `x` is not bound to 0. My question is why the `x` is treated in different way in both situations? Sorry, my question sounds ridiculous because I'm not very good in phrasing my thought, but I hope someone can help me out with it.

Comment: @Caesium95 Well, when you use the for loop `for x in foo`, you define what `x` is supposed to be. In the first loop, `x` will be the first value the iterator yields, in the second loop it will be the second value of the iterator, and so on. When you issue `while x < 5` how is Python supposed to know what `x` should be if it was not defined beforehand? It refuses the temptation to guess here and will throw an error.

Comment: @Caesium95 that is because you explicit initialize x in 1 in the while loop, in the for loop, the range function is designe to produce values in 0<=x<n when called as range(n)

Comment: @Caesium95, so... when you're writing something like this `for  x in range(5): ...` it means that x - is your iterable variable with name `x`, and after each step of `for loop` it has another value (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) . When you're writing this: `while x<5:..` it means that you're not iterating over a loop, but checking the value of `x` variable only(while is not iterator, it's checking condition only)

Comment: @pivanchy Thank you so much for your explanation, I didn't realize `while` is not an iterator until you mentioned about it. One more question from me, when I used the same variable name outside and inside the loop(the second part of my question), will the loop overwrite the value bound to the variable outside the loop or create another binding inside the loop, and so we have both variables having the same name but different values in and out of the loop? From your answer, you seemed to suggest the second one. Is that really the case?

Comment: @Caesium95, if you have a variable defined before loop, and the same variable inside the loop, you'll override this variable, and after a loop the value of this variable will be the same, as it was in the last step of a loop. For example, `i = 15; for i in range(10): print(i);` here the output will be the next: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. If you try to print `i` variable after the loop, the value will be `9`, as it was in the last step of a loop: `print(i)` prints `9`

Answer (score 1):

because the 'range' says you what is the succession of values and define num as a local value. You see few words but there is a more complex process.

An example may be Javascript language. In the for loop, you see the initial value of the value iterated through the loop, you see the maximal value and the incrementation. for(var num = 0; var <5; var+=1) in python you see for num in range(5). THe while loop is more explicit.

The fact that num is a name used for a global variable and a local variable may cause confusion. In reality the num that you see in the loop is an other variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because Python's `for` loop is more like C#'s `foreach` or JS's `for of`,
whereas VB's `for` is more like Pascal's `for`.

I'll use Pascal instead of VB, because I know it better.

Pascal's `for`:

```
var i: byte;
begin
    for i := 0 to 5 do
    begin
        writeln(i);
    end;
end.
```

Each Pascal's `for` loop can be easily replicated in Python using `range`:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

But, Python's `for` is something more:

```
for c in "HelloWorld!":
    print(c)
```

You cannot replicate it in Pascal without directly dealing with indexes.

Pascal's and VB's `for` works with indexes – they iterate from some index to another, whereas Python's `for` loop works with iterables (array, strings, files, generators and much more).